# I am facing this error highcharts.js:formatted:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined can any one help me with this

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I am creating highcharts in a function called componentDidMount, the code can be found below.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const p = this.props
    const highcharts = p.highcharts || Highcharts;
    const constructorType = p.constructorType || 'chart';
    // Create chart
    this.chart = highcharts[constructorType](this.container.current, Object.assign({}, p.options));
  }
```

I can't figure out why I get the error

```
highcharts.js:formatted:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
    at e.drawEmpty (highcharts.js:formatted:1)
    at e.redrawPoints (highcharts.js:formatted:1)
    at e.render (highcharts.js:formatted:1)
    at highcharts.js:formatted:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at B.renderSeries (highcharts.js:formatted:1)
    at B.render (highcharts.js:formatted:1)
    at B.firstRender (highcharts.js:formatted:1)
    at B.<anonymous> (highcharts.js:formatted:1)
    at g.fireEvent (highcharts.js:formatted:1)
    at B.init (highcharts.js:formatted:1)
    at B.getArgs (highcharts.js:formatted:1)
    at new B (highcharts.js:formatted:1)
    at Object.c.chart (highcharts.js:formatted:1)
    at ReactHighcharts.componentDidMount (ReactHighcharts.jsx:28)
    at ReactHighcharts.componentDidMount (highcharts.js:formatted:1)
```

Would anybody be able to help me find the problem?

Comment: Where is the Highcharts variable coming from? Where are you defining it? Could you give some more context for your readers?

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue on some online editor?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that **Highcharts is not defined**.

Where is it coming from? Could you please expand the **scope**?

It means that you are using a variable that **has never been declared.**